# How to use Statistics class from Spring Integration framework?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-integration

I need to produce Statistics for each of my RESTful API calls in my Spring MVC project, I came across `org.springframework.integration.support.management.Statistics` in Spring Integration but am not able to understand how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That class was not designed for general use; it is used to report statistics from a Spring Integration application (message channels, handlers etc).

Of course, you can use it, but you would need to dig into Spring Integration itself to see how it is used there.

It's really just a holder for reporting stats maintained elsewhere.

Such as [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/spring-integration-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/support/management/DefaultMessageChannelMetrics.java) and [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/spring-integration-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/support/management/ExponentialMovingAverage.java).